# Complex MySQL Join

Tags: mysql, join

I struggle with a MySQL Join.
These are my tables:

```
user(id, name,...);
aim(id, title,...);
aim2user(userID, aimID);
```

A user can have multiple aims.
I would like to return all aims which are NOT selectet by user X.

How is this possible?

Comment: By undertaking a little research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id from aim where id not in (select zeildID from aim2user where userID=X)
```

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't aware of NOT IN :)